# Crear nueva función en R que arroje como resultado la suma y la longitud de un vector

Tags: r

Necesito crear una nueva función en R que arroje como resultado la suma de un vector y la longitud de un vector.

Quiero que al poner una función creada por mí a través de `function()`, y seleccionando un vector, me devuelva la suma del vector. También quiero crear una función que me devuelva la longitud del vector.

He intentado esto para crear una función que devuelva valor de la suma, pero no quiero utilizar la propia función.

```
Fun_1 <- function(x) {
  while (x!=NA) {
    sum(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: Tienes que poner el código que tienes, qué has intentado, y cual es el problema concreto que encontraste. Si lo que pretendes es que te hagamos los deberes... este no es el sitio indicado.

Comment: Fun_1 <- function(x) {
  while (x!=NA) {
    sum(x)
  }
}

Comment: Si no quieres utilizar la propia función suma, haz un bucle y sumalos de 1 en 1

Answer (score 1):

En R, en general, no se necesita recorrer elementos de un vector como en otros lenguajes.
Ahora, si por algún motivo quieres recorrer los elementos del vector

```
Fun_1 <- function(x) { 
  out <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  # aqui se podría hacer algo con cada x[i] antes de sumar
    out <- out+x[i]
  }
  out
}
```